# Suddenly milions of visitors to EC2 instance run wordpress multisite. Very slow, now what?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, wordpress, slow-connection

I think the title says it all...

My dream has come true, now what? EC2 was something 2 cores maybe 4 gbs of ram... I use S3 bucket as the storage, compressed the images in Photoshop prior to the upload.

I have around 400 000 images and around 250 000 posts.

now what? My wordpress was installed in the rood directory as a multisite version of wordpress and blog was created as a separate website.

so 1 multisite root wordpress instalation> 2 websites created (the main website) and the blog website with a slug /articles (it is not really in a subdirectory)

Comment: Not really because I have a specific installation on a specific widely used server. Wordpress multisite and EC2 are such common combinations. My question was more direct because  I am a hardcore noob. I need someone to tell me "Do this and you're good the go" even if that is not the best option XD

Comment: Yes, but there you can find why we can't really help with this sort of question. In order to answer, someone would need to benchmark with similar use case and figures, while you're the one already having it all. Also, while WordPress itself is common, the installations typically aren't near the same due to different add-ons and optimizations.

Comment: I don't think it is rocket science to just say what the next step is. It's not like I am running a network of websites with 1500 servers and db across the globe and I am not aiming to squeeze that 20% efficacy out of my servers computing power. Long story short, the ec2 instance I have and any kind of wordpress installation would not be able to handle this kind of load. So what are the options out there, name them 10 and I will research each of them and try to figure out which one I need. I used bitnami wordpress installation default installation on AWS. 60% of amateur websites on AWS do it

Comment: If someone would need more info about the servers I'm all here... but if you need to benchmark it to understand why a simple wordpress website with 2 cores and 2-4 gb of ram can't handle millions of visitors, then you really can not answer this question and I asked a wrong person.

Comment: I am an expert in couple of fields and I never answer amateur questions in such manner. EVER. I either give a straight forward answer what to do OR if that is not possible I explain 5-6 possible scenarios that are most likely. Yes usually amateurs make same mistakes.. Around 90% of their mistakes and troubles can fit in those 5 or at worst 10 scenarios. Only someone who is not skilled or has no motivation to help would request benchmarks on such a silly website with millions of visitors.

Comment: You are really not being helpful here when you ask me "does this answer your question" and then you go ahead and tell me that the question can not be answered. Heh...